# Android OkHttp HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost, okhttp

### SpringBoot Server

listening to localhost:30000

### Android Client (Android Studio Emulator Nexus 5X API 30)

##### 1. using okhttp 4.10.0-RC1、Retrofit 2.9.0

##### 2. send the post request as below

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iDVl.png)

```
--> POST http://10.0.2.2:30000/user/login
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Content-Length: 45
{"account":"135******46","password":"123456"}
--> END POST (45-byte body)
```

##### 3. the request content is below

[request content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBB3.png)

##### 4. but the response is empty。 !!! And there is no any reaction in Springboot log.

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiJOb.png)

##### 5. because the response is null, OKHTTP throw a EOFException.

[http EOFException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUbLG.png)
I try the all the method about this Exception in stackover, they didn't work.
such as add Header ("Connection", "close") ("Transfer-Encoding": "identity")

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://10.0.2.2:30000/...
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://10.0.2.2:30000/...
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:204)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at com.lijiahao.sharechargingpile2.network.interceptor.TokenHeaderInterceptor.intercept(TokenHeaderInterceptor.kt:26)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at com.android.tools.profiler.agent.okhttp.OkHttp3Interceptor.intercept(OkHttp3Interceptor.java:57)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:219)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:332)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:180)
```

##### 6. I turn off the springboot server, the problem is same

##### 7. I can ping 10.0.2.2 success using adb shell in emulator

[adb shell ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVFP9.png)

```bash
adb shell
generic_x86_64:/ $ ping 10.0.2.2
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=4.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.745 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.630 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=0.922 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=0.756 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=0.826 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=0.618 ms
```

##### 8. When I run my app in real machine. Changing 10.0.2.2 to my PC IP. It can get the response successfully. The request content is same except Host.

[run success in real machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGvyu.png)

### Postman

send same post request, and get response success

### Question

It seems that there is no question in Android Client and SpringBoot Server.
The only problem is the connection between emulator and PC localhost.
**I don't know why my android studio emulator can't access localhost springboot server?**

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any fix ?

Comment: No, I use real android phone to test the program instead.

Comment: ok thanks, I will probably do the same

Answer (score 2):

You can try this fix:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

if this error occurs on a real device, then you can try this:

```
val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
httpInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
okBuilder.addInterceptor(httpInterceptor)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: real device is perfectly work without any changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case I started retrofit in a coroutine inside a scope that changed during the HTTP request, cancelling the coroutine with it.

So, check if you call retrofit inside a scope that possibly changed.